# Updating ngModel from Custom Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I've built a custom directive for generating and populating a dropdown from JSON Data.

However I want to react to a dropdown selection with a function. Therefore I want to make use of ngChange (and ngModel).
So I try to start by updating the ng-model from the directive.
The link function in the Directive should give me everything I need.
BUT the fourth parameter is undefined therefore I can't use it or even compile.

Directive TS:

```
module lsw{

lswApp.lswAppModule.directive("guiDropdown",
    () => ({
        restrict: "E",
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            data: "=",
            ctrl: "="
        },
        link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {

            element.bind("change", () => {

            });

        },
        templateUrl: "../../App_Scripts/Directives/guiDropdown.html"
    }));}
```

> "ctrls:{}"

My Idea was to make use of ctrls.$setViewValue to update ngModel

Directive HTML

```
<div class="elements">
<select name="{{data.name}}" class="dropdown-box">
    <option ng-repeat="option in ctrl" ng-value="option">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

Main View HTML

```
                    <div ng-repeat="element in HomeController.wrapper" ng-if="HomeController.trigger">
                    <div ng-switch="element.type">

                        <div ng-switch-when="dropdown">
                            <gui-dropdown data="element" ctrl="HomeController.content" ng-model="element" ng-change="HomeController.test()"></gui-dropdown>
                        </div>

                        <div ng-switch-when="textfield">
                            <gui-textfield data="element"></gui-textfield>
                        </div>

                        <div ng-switch-when="checkbox">
                            <gui-checkbox data="element"></gui-checkbox>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: which version of Angular are you using, first of all? Also the scope variable name `ctrl` for a list of options is quite misleading, I'd suggest to change it.

Comment: I'm using angular 1.5.8. Also I'm using the ctrl variable of the scope to pass in the variables of the controller. However I doubt this is the problem.

Comment: Your directive does not care where the list come from. It's better for reusability and readability to incapsulate as much as possible. However, it does not affect the performance indeed.
Regarding your question itself, I don't see why Angular does not give you ngModelController, but for this functionality I would use (and used) callback bindings, something like it this example from the docs. https://plnkr.co/edit/uXwghyhSvFU6JEhkG3QY?p=preview